# "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" Exception error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

In windows 10, I am running the terminal as an administrator,

It is giving an exception error.

I am trying to upgrade pip but it is giving an error:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/84/23ed6a1796480a6f1a2d38f2802901d078266bda38388954d01d3f2e821d/pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\user1\appdata\roaming\python\python38\scripts\
   from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\~cripts
  Moving to c:\users\user1\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages\pip-19.3.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\~ip-19.3.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\user1\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages\pip\
   from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 446, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 58, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 858, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 487, in move_wheel_files
    wheel.move_wheel_files(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 594, in move_wheel_files
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 402, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 330, in make
    return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 391, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 295, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 231, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 370, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes'
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

What should I do to upgrade pip?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
easy_install -U pip
```

If the above command doesn't work, try the following :

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

Comment: This helped me to get the Version but now I am trying to install a local package. I typed this and got this error what should I do?: pip install Gaussian_Package/.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\distributionspackage\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'